# How do I print a UTF-16 string in Zig?

Tags: unicode, utf-16, zig

I've been trying to code a UTF-16 string structure, and although the standard library provides a `unicode` module, it doesn't seem to provide a way to print out a slice of `u16`.
I've tried this:

```
const std = @import("std");
const unicode = std.unicode;
const stdout = std.io.getStdOut().outStream();

pub fn main() !void {
    const unicode_str = unicode.utf8ToUtf16LeStringLiteral(" hello! ");
    try stdout.print("{}\n", .{unicode_str});
}
```

This outputs:

```
[12:0]u16@202e9c
```

Is there a way to print a unicode string (`[]u16`) without converting it back into a non-unicode string (`[]u8`)?

Comment: who said that UTF-8 is non-Unicode? All UTF encodings (UTF-1/7/8/9/16/32...) can represent all Unicode code points

Comment: @phuclv I apologize, I have fallen prey to the informal use of the word "unicode" to mean "non-ASCII". (e.g. python 3 unicode support)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `[]const u8` and `[]const u16` store encoded unicode codepoints. Unicode codepoints fit within the range 0..1,114,112 so an actual unicode string with one array index per codepoint would have to be `[]const u21`. utf-8 and utf-16 both require encoding for codepoints that don't fit. Unless there is a compatability reason for utf-16 (like some windows functions), you should probably be using `[]const u8` unicode strings.

To print utf-16 to a utf-8 stream, you have to decode utf-16 and re-encode it into utf-8. There is currently no formatting specifier to do this automatically.

You can either convert the entire string at once, requiring allocation:

```rs
const utf8string = try std.unicode.utf16leToUtf8Alloc(alloc, utf16le);
```

Or, without allocation:

```rs
var writer = std.io.getStdOut().writer();
var it = std.unicode.Utf16LeIterator.init(utf16le);
while (try it.nextCodepoint()) |codepoint| {
    var buf: [4]u8 = [_]u8{undefined} ** 4;
    const len = try std.unicode.utf8Encode(codepoint, &buf);
    try writer.writeAll(buf[0..len]);
}
```

Note that this will be very slow without using a buffered writer if you are writing somewhere that requires a syscall to write.

Comment: Is there a way to widen the standard output stream to utf-16?

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick Output streams currently write bytes and byte slices only. You can propose adding a utf-16 writer and formatter if you have a compelling use case like a platform or code that requires utf-16.